# Modifying an input value before submitting it with Javascript or HTML

Tags: javascript, html

So essentially, I have an input and I want to modify the value before the user submits it. All I want to do is add a string to the end of this inputs value. I thought it would be something like:

```
<form action="myURL" onsubmit="myFunction" method="POST">
  <input id="myID" value="someValue" />
  <button type="submit">Press Me!</button>
</form>

<script>
myFunction()
{
    var x = document.getElementById("myID").value;
    document.getElementById("myID").value = x + "myString";
}
</script>
```

However, when the form is submitted the appended string is not sent and only the original string makes it. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can submit the form using JavaScript:

Please Note: The function name should be preceded by the *function* keyword.

```js
document.getElementById('myForm').onsubmit = myFunction;

function myFunction(){
    var x = document.getElementById("myID").value;
    document.getElementById("myID").value = x + "myString";
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm" action="myURL" method="POST">
  <input id="myID" value="someValue" />
  <button type="submit">Press Me!</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the changes in `onclick` event of the submit button instead of `onsubmit`.

```
<form action="myURL" id="myForm" method="POST">
  <input id="myID" value="someValue" />
  <button type="submit" onclick="myFunction(event)">Press Me!</button>
</form>

<script>
myFunction(event)
{
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var x = document.getElementById("myID").value;
    document.getElementById("myID").value = x + "myString";
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Clicking the submit button, for all it's worth, hasn't got as much to do with form submission as many people believe. For one, a form can be submitted in different ways -- a user agent like Firefox or Google Chrome, to name a few, does so when the user presses Enter on their keyboard and an input control of the form is currently focused. Your `myFunction` will not be called then, and you will miss the submission. Use the "submit" event that the user agent fires on form elements, instead -- that's what it's for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke the function in the submit event handler with brackets i.e. `onsubmit="functionToCall()"` instead of `onsubmit="functionToCall"`.

You need the function keyword in front of the name of the function: you would write `function functionName(){}` instead of just `functionName(){}`.

You should set the variable x to equal the input element, not the input element's value so you will not need to query the DOM again.

```html
<form action="myURL" onsubmit="myFunction()" method="POST">
  <input id="myID" value="someValue" />
  <button type="submit">Press Me!</button>
</form>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
    event.preventDefault();//for demonstrative purposes
    var x = document.getElementById("myID");
    x.value += "myString";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why would they need to prevent submission, the question doesn't mention anything about that?

Comment: @amn Changed my answer.